# how to pytest a pyqt application that uses argparse for input parameters

Tags: pyqt, mocking, pytest

I have a PyQt application that uses argparse to pass some argument.

I managed to write a simple test to see if the app starts

but I cannot set/mock the argparse arguments
I know it because inside the code I have some try/except like this

```
    try:
        if args.erase_data:
            pass

    except NameError:
        logger.error("Error in parsing erase_data input argument \n")
```

that during the tests fail, while they do not fail if I run the app.
I tried this to mock args

```
import os
import pathlib

# import pdb
import sys
from unittest import mock

import pytest
from PyQt5 import QtTest
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pytestqt.plugin import QtBot

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
src_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[1].absolute()
print(src_dir)
sys.path.append(src_dir.as_posix())

GUI = __import__("GUI")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def qtbot_session(qapp, request):
    result = QtBot(qapp)
    with capture_exceptions() as e:
        print(getattr(e, "message", repr(e)))
        yield result
    print("  TEARDOWN qtbot")


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def Viewer(request):

    with mock.patch.object(sys, "argv", ["",'-d','2']):
        print("mocking sys argv")
        print(sys.argv)
        # pdb.set_trace()
        app, app_window = GUI.main()

        qtbotbis = QtBot(app)
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(0.5 * 1000)
        assert app_window.isVisible()
        return app, app_window, qtbotbis
```

but args is still not set.
any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You say "I have a PyQt application that uses argparse to pass some argument." but I don't see any reference to [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in the code you provided. Are you sure you are using it? Qt-applications likely use [QCommandLineParser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html), but I don't see that either.

Comment: I found a workaround to this issue and used sys.argv to read the passed arguments instead of args in the main. and this worked out fine as I can finally mock in test